# Segment Interval Search

Tags: algorithm, intervals, binary-search

We have set of intervals `[angle1,angle2]`. I want to find out the optimal value of theta `[-180,180]` which lies in the maximum number of intervals. Value of theta can be float. I tried With linear search and check for all the intervals but as value of theta can be float, I think even binary search can't work.

Comment: Binary search works absolutely fine on floats...

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? What do you mean by `maximum no of intervals`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree binary search absolutely work on floats but in the problem context how can we apply binary search , can you please put some light on it .

Comment: Ohh yes@IanMercer corrected , Thanks to pointing this .

Comment: Do you want the search to wrap around 360? i.e. an interval could be [359,2]?

Comment: @Yes Ian interval it  could be [359,2] ,I forgot to thought about that case

Comment: @Rishav for example [1,5] [3,7] ,[4,9]   4,5 lies in 3 interval and 1 lies only in one interval .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the interval start and end values into a single list with a corresponding value for 'S' or 'E' for each one.

Scan the list, when you hit an S increment a counter, when you hit an E decrement a counter. If the counter is higher than the highest value seen so far remember the S and E values for that segment.

For the wrap-around case, simply split each interval that wraps (i.e. angle2 < angle1) into two pieces, one either side of zero. Add [angle1,360] and [0,angle2] as new intervals into the starting set.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Mercer This looks good to me , i am not able to upvote your answer but it certainly will solve my problem . Once i have enough rating i will upvote your answer .

Comment: will it work for both [0,360] and [-180,180] format ?

Comment: But Ian wrap around cases will be there .

Comment: for wrap around cases  we can split it like that too [ angle1-360,0) and [0,angle2] that's what you mean correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: I was using - to mean the interval, I'll change it to a comma.